# Troubling with writing data into a holding register using pymodbus

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus

I am troubling with writing into a holding register using pymodbus. I can read the register data using this library (pymodbus). But when I want to write data into a single register, it gives me the output shown in the picture.

[image]

I have a Modbus device with limited documentation and I have tried to write data into the register by searching the problem but could not found. This is my code

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='COM3',bytesize=8,  stopbits=1,  parity='N', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)

client.connect()
print('Çonnected')
write=client.write_register(address=0x8000,value=0x13A, unit=0x11)
#read=client.read_holding_registers(address=0x8000,count=4, unit=0x11)  
if(write):
    print(write)

client.close()
```

[N.B]: When I write data using the third-party tool by sending bellow code then it's working fine.

`11 06 80 04 00 04 00 00 32 36 C1 0E`

I could not find what was wrong with my python code.

I apologize for my English writing.

Comment: `11 06 80 04 00 04 00 00 32 36 C1 0E` does not look like a valid Modbus RTU request; which application did this come from?  `11 06 80 04 00 04 E2 98` would be a valid RTU request (writing `4` to register `0x8005`). Please provide some information about the controller you are communicating with (perhaps it does not fully adhere to the Modbus standard?).